# How to change the values of the children of an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
  const mockObjPanoramas = [{
    'id': '7oADHnGZcr',
    'appMarkers': [{
      'panoId': '7oADHnGZcr',
      'color': 'red',
      'x': 0,
      'y': 0,
      'z': 1000
    }, {
      'panoId': '8szmQ8ELKs',
      'color': 'red',
      'x': 100,
      'y': 0,
      'z': 1000
    }]
  }, {
    'id': '8szmQ8ELKs',
    'appMarkers': [{
      'panoId': '7oADHnGZcr',
      'color': 'green',
      'x': 0.1352234,
      'y': -0.2600403,
      'z': 0.9960099
    }, {
      'panoId': '8szmQ8ELKs',
      'color': 'green',
      'x': 0.03900146,
      'y': 0.295959,
      'z': 0.9169907
    }]
  }]
```

I want to apply the following formula to each `appMarker` and return a new array:

```
(x, y, z) = (-z, y, -x) * 1000
```

So I did this:

```
function parseUnityMarkers (mockObjPanoramas) {
  return mockObjPanoramas.map(mockObjPanorama => {
    return mockObjPanorama.appMarkers.map(appMarker => {
      const depth = 1000
      appMarker.x = -appMarker.z * depth
      appMarker.y = appMarker.y * depth
      appMarker.z = -appMarker.x * depth
    })
  })
}
```

However, I get this:[image]

What am I doing wrong?

**NOTE:** I want to return a new array identical as the original one. But with the values of x, y and z of the `appMarkers` changed.

Comment: would you change the original object, or return a new independent result?

Comment: @Nina Scholz Return a new result. Identical as the original but with the value of the `appMarkers` changed.

Comment: Added a second section that should keep your original data intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made it simple (I like to do things in a simple way :) ):

```
    function parseUnityMarkers(mockObjPanoramas) {
      for(var i=0; i < mockObjPanoramas.length; i++){
        var temp1 = mockObjPanoramas[i];
        for(var j=0; j < temp1.appMarkers.length; j++) {
          var temp2 = temp1.appMarkers[j];
          const depth = 1000;
          var x = temp2.x;
          temp2.x = -temp2.z * depth
          temp2.y = temp2.y * depth
          temp2.z = -x * depth
        }
      }
      return mockObjPanoramas;
    }
```

One important thing :

when you are doing :

```
  appMarker.x = -appMarker.z * depth
  appMarker.y = appMarker.y * depth
  appMarker.z = -appMarker.x * depth
```

> Note that you have made the `z` value as : `-z * depth * depth`
>   because you already replaced `x` with `-z * depth`.

```js
const mockObjPanoramas = [{
  'id': '7oADHnGZcr',
  'appMarkers': [{
    'panoId': '7oADHnGZcr',
    'color': 'red',
    'x': 0,
    'y': 0,
    'z': 1000
  }, {
    'panoId': '8szmQ8ELKs',
    'color': 'red',
    'x': 100,
    'y': 0,
    'z': 1000
  }]
}, {
  'id': '8szmQ8ELKs',
  'appMarkers': [{
    'panoId': '7oADHnGZcr',
    'color': 'green',
    'x': 0.1352234,
    'y': -0.2600403,
    'z': 0.9960099
  }, {
    'panoId': '8szmQ8ELKs',
    'color': 'green',
    'x': 0.03900146,
    'y': 0.295959,
    'z': 0.9169907
  }]
}];

function parseUnityMarkers(mockObjPanoramas) {
  for(var i=0; i < mockObjPanoramas.length; i++){
    var temp1 = mockObjPanoramas[i];
    for(var j=0; j < temp1.appMarkers.length; j++) {
      var temp2 = temp1.appMarkers[j];
      const depth = 1000;
      var x = temp2.x;
      temp2.x = -temp2.z * depth
      temp2.y = temp2.y * depth
      temp2.z = -x * depth
    }
  }
  return mockObjPanoramas;
}

console.log(parseUnityMarkers(mockObjPanoramas));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing a return statement from your second map call:

```
function parseUnityMarkers (mockObjPanoramas) {
  return mockObjPanoramas.map(mockObjPanorama => {
    return mockObjPanorama.appMarkers.map(appMarker => {
      const depth = 1000
      appMarker.x = -appMarker.z * depth
      appMarker.y = appMarker.y * depth
      appMarker.z = -appMarker.x * depth
      return appMarker;
    })
  })
}
```

However, you're going to run into another problem.  You're overwriting the value of `appMarker.x`, and then trying to access the original value afterwards.  Also, you're actually overwriting your original data.  You can keep your original data from changing like this:

```
function parseUnityMarkers (mockObjPanoramas) {
  return mockObjPanoramas.map(mockObjPanorama => {
    return {
      id: mockObjPanorama.id,
      appMarkers: mockObjPanorama.appMarkers.map(appMarker => {
        const depth = 1000
        return {
          panoId: appMarker.panoId,
          color: appMarker.color,
          x: -appMarker.z * depth,
          y: appMarker.y * depth,
          z: -appMarker.x * depth
        };
      })
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And I realized The parents of the children are gone!

Comment: I made a change so that the entire data structure should be duplicated, even the parent.